# Should I ask for help finding a chip in the EE forum?

Tags: discussion

I'm looking for a specific chip, which I know how to use - just can't find one with enough parallel channels (so its not really a knowledge question as such...) but can't find a suitable candidate. I've looked on all the usual sites, but can't find one. Is this a reasonable question to ask in the EE forum, if not - where could I ask this?

Comment: Recommendation questions are offtopic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a try with the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=electronics.stackexchange.com), if you're lucky you'll find someone who can give you advice.

I think a question regarding component search is too specific to be a good question.

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much - didn't want to have a massively downvoted question...

Comment: Nothing ventured, nothing gained.  I'd think about how to ask the question within the rules.  Which is what you are doing here.  Outline what you have found and odds are someone will answer or answer in the comments.  At the end of the day, what is more important to you.  A negative rating on a question you can delete or an answer to the question.  Ultimately, it is up to the community to judge, but if you can't find a part and you outline what you have done and you are seeking a solution, you may get a partial answer.  Something is always better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I ask for help finding a chip in the EE forum?

No.  We don't do component recommendations here.

Comment: Wow. Whoever downvoted this has probably not read the [help](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, or even seen the close reason _"Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic"_.